# How do I beat Hraesvelg?

Tags: megami-quest-2

I've got far more than enough power to win the fight, but none of my attacks hit - they all miss. I tried dialling up MAG on a character to see if that would do it, but that just healed me. How do I hit Hraesvelg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dial up SPD to at least **10**, on each character in order to be able to hit Hraesvelg.